# Concurrency with loops

Tags: ada

it's me again.
So i have a problem with concurrency in Ada. Basically part of my program looks like that:

```
for i in 1..it loop

    for x in 1..A loop
        for y in 1..B
            --tab(x,y):=...
        end loop;
    end loop;

    for x in 1..A loop
        for y in 1..B
            --tab(x,y):=...
        end loop;
    end loop;

end loop;
```

Inside this loops are some calculations. What i intend to do is to make these two 'inside' loops work concurrently. Either one element from loop 1, then one element element from loop 2 or little less 'symmetric'. But generally i want it to look like that: first iteration, two 'inside' loops work concurrently, all operations finish, iteration finishes. Second iteration same and so on.. My questions is: can i do it with ENTRY and ACCEPT statements? Or will this require something more? If You could just point me the right solution, because i've seen many examples but none suiting my issue.

Comment: Before asking anymore questions, you should go back to your previous ones and **accept** helpful answers.

Comment: You're right, just fixed it.

Comment: We may need a little more information to help design a parallel implementation. For example, if `tab(x,y)` is shared, and updated by both processes, it will probably be best implemented as a "protected object" and you won't need entry/accept statements to synchronise access to it. These (aka Rendezvous) are probably best reserved for messages passed from one task to another. If your loops don't interact like that, you can use lighter weight tasks without rendezvous.

Comment: tab(x,y) is shared object, but each process 'has access' only to half of the array(his part), so it actually looks like they don't share any structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two inner loops really don't share any data, you can do it loke this:

```
task First;
task Second;

task body First is
   ...
begin
   for i in 1 .. it loop
      for x in 1 .. A loop
         for y in 1 .. B loop
             ...
         end loop;
      end loop;
   end loop;
end First;

task body Second is
   ...
begin
   for i in 1 .. it loop
      for x in 1 .. A loop
         for y in 1 .. B loop
             ...
         end loop;
      end loop;
   end loop;
end Second;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i was wrong. They do share this array in minimal way, but they do (half + one column). So the 'main' iteration must end when two processess finish.

Comment: One (lazy) option is then to put in a rendezvous there to synchronise.  (The "proper" is to copy the shared data at the appropriate times.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to limit the amount of tasks to the amount of cores supported by the system. See this example on calculating pi:
https://github.com/AdaDoom3/OldStuff/blob/master/time_pi.adb

Comment: Possibly, though it is often best to model the problem at hand using as many tasks as is natural -- this keeps your code higher-level and more portable.

Comment: But in this case it looks like the natural form is a single task.